# How to action script to link a button to a HTML page?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a page in which I have used some flash components as buttons, to which I want to link to another HTML page but don't know how to do it. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 6):

You have to place a event listener on your button to listen click events.

```
yourButton_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, onClick, false, 0, true);
function onClick(e:MouseEvent):void{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("page.html"), "_self"); // change "_self" to "_blank" if want to it open in other tab or window. More info in the links I wrote below.
}
```

Here are good resources on [links](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3link/) and [events](http://www.republicofcode.com/tutorials/flash/as3events/).

Comment: It's so complicated, I knew a smaller one like getURl... something like this which I don't remember. Can you tell what's that?

Comment: getURL was in AS2. It's not that complicated, you just have to call navigateToURL and pass a URLRequest as parameter. Please read those 2 links I wrote below the code if you want to have a good understanding on that. :)

Comment: Yes. Just make sure you'll add the listener using the name of your button (as I called "yourButton_mc" in my code).

Comment: I am thinking to make 6 buttons in a single .swf file. This script is not working there. Why don't you even give "getURL..." script? May that work...

Answer (score 2):

In Flash, click the button you will be using and give it an instance name, (under the properties panel), and change the code accordingly.

```
// URLRequest variable(where to navigate)
var pageOnAnySiteURL:URLRequest = new URLRequest("www.example.com/useGoogle");

// Navigation function
function navigateFunc(event:MouseEvent):void {
   navigateToURL(pageOnAnySiteURL, "_blank");
}

// Fire off that event when button is clicked in FLash
buttonInstanceName_mc.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, navigateFunc);
```