# Get buttons to work inside animated interactive movie clip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have a filmstrip animation with 5 images (meant to be buttons to get urls) inside the filmstrip movie clip. I've only created a button of the first image so far.  It works when it is not in the movie clip; however, once the movie clip is created that contains the button, it no longer works.

Additionally, the buttons have a rollover effect that works in or outside of the movie clip. If the button can detect the mouse over inside the movie clip, why can't it detect the mouse click?

Super grateful for any advice. I'm not well versed in AS, so you might want to dumb it down a bit.

ActionScript

```
var count = 1;
rtBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightScroll);
lftBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leftScroll);

function panelOver() {
//  this.onEnterFrame = scrollPanel;
//  delete this.onRollOver;
}

function rightScroll(e:Event){

    if (count < 5){
    count++;
panel.x += 150;
    }else{
        count = 5;
    }
    //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rightAnimate);
    //function rightAnimate(event:Event) {
    //panel.x -= 140; //Math.round(140/7);
//}
}
function leftScroll(e:Event){
    if (count > 1){
        count --;
        panel.x -= 150;
    }else{
        count=1;
    }


    //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,leftAnimate);
    //function leftAnimate(event:Event) {
    //panel.x += 140;// - Math.round(.5);
//}

}



/* Click to Go to Web Page
Clicking on the specified symbol instance loads the URL in a new browser window.

Instructions:
1. Replace http://www.adobe.com with the desired URL address.
   Keep the quotation marks ("").
*/

snowbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
}
```

Comment: You may find the answer here

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11782874/how-to-action-script-to-link-a-button-to-a-html-page

Comment: If you could post some code, stuff like where you're adding the button to the `MovieClip`, and the clicking and rollover triggers, that would be helpful.

Comment: var count = 1;
rtBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, rightScroll);
lftBtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, leftScroll);

function panelOver() {
// this.onEnterFrame = scrollPanel;
// delete this.onRollOver;
}

function rightScroll(e:Event){

 if (count < 5){
 count++;
panel.x += 150;
 }else{
  count = 5;
 }
 //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,rightAnimate);
 //function rightAnimate(event:Event) {
 //panel.x -= 140; //Math.round(140/7);
//}
}

Comment: function leftScroll(e:Event){
 if (count > 1){
  count --;
  panel.x -= 150;
 }else{
  count=1;
 }
 
 
 //addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME,leftAnimate);
 //function leftAnimate(event:Event) {
 //panel.x += 140;// - Math.round(.5);
//}

}
/* Click to Go to Web Page
Clicking on the specified symbol instance loads the URL in a new browser window.



snowbtn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_3);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_3(event:MouseEvent):void
{
 navigateToURL(new URLRequest("http://www.adobe.com"), "_blank");
}

Comment: That's all the code I have so far which allows for the left to right animation of the panel (or filmstrip) of images. On the main timeline, I have only frame #1 used which includes left/right scroll btns, a mask for the panel and the panel itself. Inside the panel are five images on one layer in frame #1.

Comment: Each image should be it's own button that goes to a separate url. I'm happy to share the .fla file via Creative Cloud.  Let me know.  Your help is so very appreciated!! Tahnk you!!

Comment: Can you insert the code into your question for the sake of clarity? I'm having difficulty following your code since it's not formatted.

Comment: Hi David - Thanks for looking into this! I added the code to my question. Thanks again!

Comment: I found an extremely solution to this problem. Simply add panel. before the button instance name.